# Is there a way to express an power law decay as a series of exponentials?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a power law equation: 
$$
y= a*b^x
$$
Is it possible to approximate this equation with series of exponentials similar to the following?
$$
y =  c*\sum_i e^{k_i * x}
$$
Thank you

Comment: For optimal approximation of power law by exponentials see the following paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0605149.pdf

Answer (score 5):

Yes, even a single exponential, because $a b^x$ is the same as $c e^{kx}$ with $a=c$ and $b=e^k$.  But "power law" usually means a multiple of $x^{-r}$, not $b^x$.  That can't be written as a sum of exponential decays, but *can* be written as a weighted average (= integral) of exponentials $e^{-xt}$ using the Gamma function:
$$
x^{-r} = \frac1{\Gamma(r)} \int_0^\infty t^{r-1} e^{-xt} dt.
$$

Comment: Dear Noam, could you please take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/252071/what-is-the-spinor-genus-of-the-leech-lattice ? I think my answer is correct, but I also think you would know for sure.

Comment: Um, surely this request doesn't belong on this completely unrelated query...
(and you have my e-mail address.)
To your question, that seems right (though I didn't check the numbers),
though probably unnecessary because splitting into several spinor genera
requires discriminants of high valuation, and the Leech/Niemeier genus has
dicsriminant whose valuations are as smaller as possible!  But I've not
studied this aspect of the theory carefully enough to be certain of
this argument.

Comment: Noam, thank you. Between email and a comment of this type, I expected the comment to be less of an intrusion. In future I will use email or forget the thing. Gerry Myerson once made a similar comment when I called his attention to something in this way, so I guess I had this backwards. Sorry.

Comment: @Noam - Could you suggest any textbooks/papers where the formula you quoted is derived? Would be of great help, thanks.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies could you add a derivation?

Comment: This integral is well known and should be in most integral tables.
The change of variable $xt=u$ converts the integral to
$x^{-r} \int_0^\infty u^{r-1} e^{-u} \, du$,
and $\int_0^\infty u^{r-1} e^{-u} \, du$ is the definition of $\Gamma(r)$.

Comment: Thank you! I have a small related question: is there some way to interpret $\frac{t^{r-1}}{\Gamma(r)}$ as a probability distribution over $t$?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer If you restrict $t$ to be $\in [0,1]$, your equation gives $\operatorname{Beta}(r,1)$ distribution